# How to get Phoenix to listen on port 4000?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to get my Phoenix app to listen on port 4000, but it's not working.  First, I generate my production app with `MIX_ENV=prod mix release --env=prod`.  Then, I rsync the `_build` directory to my server.  Then I run `PORT=4000 ./_build/prod/rel/rumbl/bin/rumbl start`.  Then when I `curl localhost:4000`, I get no response.

Here's my `config/prod.exs`:

```
use Mix.Config

config :rumbl, Rumbl.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [host: "localhost", port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json"

config :logger, level: :info
import_config "prod.secret.exs"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
http: [port: {:system, "4000"}],
```

it should read as:

```
http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
```

and the system environment variable `PORT` should be set and exported:

```
export PORT=4000
```

e.g. in your shell profile. Also you need to add

```
load_from_system_env: true,
server: true,
root: ".",
```

lines to your config.

If you do not want to configure it, just do:

```
http: [port: "4000"],
```

`{:system, "4000"}` is basically trying to read env variable `4000`.

---

*Sidenote:* it’s better to make the next line to exactly correspond this setting:

```
url: [host: "localhost", port: {:system, "PORT"}],
```

Comment: I modified my config file to use system variables, but I'm still not able to access the site.

Comment: I have updated an answer: `load_from_system_env: true` matters.